# How to generate menu.lua for Awesome WM from GNOME menu?

Tags: gnome, awesome

Following up on a [question about the Awesome WM menu contents](https://askubuntu.com/q/165657/10371), I'd like to figure out *how to import the GNOME menu in its entirety* into the menu.lua file for Awesome.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like [xdg-menu-to-awesome-wm](https://github.com/chouilleur/xdg-menu-to-awesome-wm) does the job:

```
python awesome-xdg-menu.py > ~/.config/awesome/menu.lua
```

Then modify `rc.lua` to include it according to the readme (perhaps replacing the Debian menu). *Now if only there was some way to avoid converting every time I install a GUI application...*

Answer (score 3):

I use [awesome-freedesktop](https://github.com/terceiro/awesome-freedesktop) which reads the menu files when awesome is started so there is no need to rerun it manually.